# How to format bibliography titles as section, subsection, and subsubsection

Tags: biblatex, formatting

How can I format the titles "Books" and "Articles" to appear as `\subsections`?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{NZSM446.bib}

\begin{document}
\section{Sections Available}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\section{Bibliography}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title={Books},type=book,sorting=nyt]
\printbibliography[title={Articles},type=article,sorting=nyt]
\end{document}
```

Desired output:

[image]

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can add `heading=subbibliography` when issuing `\printbibliography`.

Also, load `biblatex` with the option `defernumbers=true` when printing different bibliographies with different types.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{NZSM446.bib}

\begin{document}
\section{Sections Available}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\section{Bibliography}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title={Books},type=book,sorting=nyt,heading=subbibliography]
\printbibliography[title={Articles},type=article,sorting=nyt,heading=subbibliography]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

In response to your edited question, you can also add `heading=subbibnumbered` when issuing `\printbibliography` to achieve what you want.

Notice that, if you want, you can also substitute (for consistency)

```
\section{Bibliography}
```

with

```
\printbibheading[title={Bibliography},heading=bibnumbered]
```

So, the definitive MWE could be:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{NZSM446.bib}

\begin{document}
\section{Sections Available}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\nocite{*}
\printbibheading[title={Bibliography},heading=bibnumbered]
\printbibliography[title={Books},type=book,sorting=nyt,heading=subbibnumbered]
\printbibliography[title={Articles},type=article,sorting=nyt,heading=subbibnumbered]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Αναξ see the edited answer.