# Adding biblatex bibliography sections to table of contents

Tags: biblatex, table-of-contents, bibliographies, sectioning

[This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134958/how-to-format-bibliography-titles-as-section-subsection-and-subsubsection?newreg=1be1d0daf75b41eaa4661432f16a81ae) shows nicely how to create a sectioned bibliography with biblatex. However, the section titles do not appear automatically in the table of contents. Is there a parameter for the `\printbibliography` command that will do this for me or do I have to go via the standard `\section`, `\subsection` commands?

Comment: Hi, you should add the key `heading=bibintoc` as optional argument to `\printbibliography`.

Comment: Thanks, that does work. However, the bibliography section all have the same indent in the toc. I would expect `\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography ...]` to produce section level indents. Using `\section` commands instead works better.

Comment: Depending on the class either `heading=bibnumbered,` or `heading=subbibnumbered,` will use `\section`. The other options will use slightly different commands with different outcomes. We can only tell you which option to use if you can show us a small example document that reproduces your section and bibliography setup and explain exactly which output you would like to see

Answer (score 0):

As commented on the original post I arrive at the desired format using standard sectioning, but for biblatex alone I guess I am missing one more level i.e. "heading=subsubbibintoc". The biblatex version is commented out in the MWE below.

```
\documentclass[headings=optiontoheadandtoc]{scrbook}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, defernumbers=true, style=authoryear, dashed=false, maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{The Big Bang}
\section{First Few Minuites}
\subsection{First Few Seconds}
\nocite{*}

% desired toc listing using standard sectioning
\chapter[nonumber=true]{Bibliography}
\section[nonumber=true]{General References}
\printbibliography[heading=none, type=article]
\section[nonumber=true]{Own Publications}
\subsection[nonumber=true]{Peer-Reviewed Journal Articles}
\printbibliography[heading=none, keyword={primary}]
\subsection[nonumber=true]{Conference Contributions}
\printbibliography[heading=none, keyword={secondary}]

%  not desired toc listing
% \printbibheading[title={Bibliography}, heading=bibintoc]
% \printbibliography[heading=bibliography, heading=subbibintoc, type=article, title={General References}]
% \printbibheading[title={Own Publications}, heading=subbibintoc]
% \printbibliography[heading=bibliography, heading=subbibintoc, keyword={primary}, title={Peer-reviewed Articles}]
% \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography, heading=subbibintoc, keyword={secondary}, title={Conference Contributions}]

\end{document}
```

[image]